# Fluid Typography Linear Transition: How is the calc()-expression computed?

Tags: css, font-size, typography, css-calc

Using the approach described by e.g. [Mike Riethmuller](https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/fluid-type-calc-examples/) of using calc() to achieve a fluid transition from a minimum font-size to a maximum font-size, the result returned from calc() and displayed in the browser is somewhat puzzling to me (and not as intended). How does the following code return this result for h1 at a viewport size from 25rem up to 80rem? (I've included the calc() for the html font-size as well, since it also scales with h1 proportionate to it)

Result:

> h1 calc(0.450091rem + 3.38364vw)

Code:

```
html {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 25rem) {
  html {
    font-size: calc(1.125rem + 0.25 * ((100vw - 25rem) / 55));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 80rem) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.375rem;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.296rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 25rem) {
  h1 {
    font-size: calc(1.296rem + 1.861 * ((100vw - 25rem) / 55));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 80rem) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.157rem;
  }
}
```

The result is a "jumpy" non-fluid transition as we enter the viewport min-width of 80rem and reach the max font-size of 3.157rem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing the `font-size` of the `html` element you are then changing the `rem` value. It's somehow tricky but let's follow the code and the calculation step by step.

Initially we will have  a `font-size` equal to `1.125rem` within `html` and we will have a `font-size` for `h1` equal to `1.125 * 1.296 * 16px = 23.328px`. For the media query we will have `25rem = 25*16px = 400px` and `80rem = 80*16px = 1280px`<sup>**1**</sup>.

After `400px` (the first media query), it become tricky because we will have dynamic values of font-size with `html` thus the `font-size` for `h1` will be something like:

```
 (1.296* P *16px + 1.861 * ((100vw - (25 * P * 16px) ) / 55))
```

Where

```
 P = (1.125 * 16px + 0.25 * ((100vw - 25 * 16px) / 55))
```

Now when we reach the next media query (`1280px`), we will have `100vw` equal to `1280px` (not `80rem` like we may think!) and `P = 1.375rem` so the result considering the forumla **before** `1280px` will be `1.296 * 1.375 * 16px + 1.861 *((1280px - 25 * 1.375 * 16px)/55) = 28,512px + 24.7px = 53.21px`.

And the result considering the formula **after** `1280px` will be `3.157 * 1.375 * 16px = 69.454px`. This explain why you don't have the transition and the culprit was the `100vw` that is equal to `1280px` and not `80rem` so you want have the intendend result of `(80 - 25)/55 = 1`

Following the formula you found we will have the same result:

> h1 calc(0.450091rem + 3.38364vw)

when at `80rem` `100vw` will be `1280px` and `3.38364vw` will be `43.13px` and `0.45rem` will be `0.45 * 1.375 * 16px = 9.9px` and the total `53.03px`.

The result is also logical because `calc` will reduce the formula to group all the same unit together:

```
calc(1.296rem + 1.861 * ((100vw - 25rem) / 55))
calc(1.296rem + 1.861 * (1.8181vw - 0.4545rem)
calc(1.296rem + 3.3834vw - 0.8459rem)
calc(0.4501rem + 3.3834vw)
```

[image]

---

**<sup>1</sup>Why in the media query we don't multiply with the value used in html?**

Considering the below calculation, we may think that within the media query we should also consider the same logic thus `25rem` and `80rem` should also be dynamic. This is not the case for media query as detailed in [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#units):

> Relative length units in media queries are based on the **initial value**, which means that units are never based on results of declarations.

So whataver the the value of `font-size` used within `html` is, we will always consider the intial value of `16px` for `1rem` inside media query.

<sup>There will be some slight difference between the values obtained using different method due to some rounding. The purpose is not to provide exact calculation but to explain the calculation.</sup>

Comment: OK, so to put it another way: The problem is that using rem for media queries 1rem=initial value (e.g. 16px set as the browser default). However, using rem within an element such as a calc for setting font-size, 1rem = the font-size of html (at that point). That is to say, in the media query min-width of 80rem=1280px whereas in the calc 80rems=80*html font-size. Is that correctly understood?

Comment: @Zaphod yes and also 100vw has nothing to do with rem values and is equal to size of viewport at any time. For this case within the boundary of 80rem 100vw is 1280px because the viewport is 1280px that was caluculated initially as 80*16px.